# Movielabs manifest element encoding error againts xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, metadata

I have xml manifest file (this is a part of it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

<manifest:MediaManifest
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:manifest="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.5/manifest"
xmlns:md="http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<manifest:Compatibility>
    <manifest:SpecVersion>1.5</manifest:SpecVersion>
    <manifest:Profile>http://www.movielabs.com/md/manifest/v1.5/manifest-v1.5.xsd</manifest:Profile>
</manifest:Compatibility>

<manifest:Inventory>
    <manifest:Audio
        AudioTrackID="md:audtrackid:org:blueskyfilm.com:licks1:feature.audio51.en">
        <md:Type>primary</md:Type>
        <md:Language>en</md:Language>
        <md:TrackReference>2</md:TrackReference>
        <md:Encoding>
            <md:Codec>PCM</md:Codec>
            <md:ChannelMapping>L,R,C,LFE,LS,RS</md:ChannelMapping>
        </md:Encoding>
        <md:Channels>5.1</md:Channels>
        <manifest:ContainerReference>
            <manifest:ContainerIdentifier>
                <md:Namespace>md</md:Namespace>
                <md:Identifier>md:apid:org:blueskyfilm.com:licks1:feature.audio51.en</md:Identifier>
                <md:Location>file://resources/Licks_FTR_1080_2398p_51en_20en.mov</md:Location>
            </manifest:ContainerIdentifier>
        </manifest:ContainerReference>
    </manifest:Audio>
    <manifest:Audio
        AudioTrackID="md:audtrackid:org:blueskyfilm.com:licks1:feature.audio20.en">
        <md:Type>primary</md:Type>
        <md:Language>en</md:Language>
        <md:Encoding>
            <md:Codec>PCM</md:Codec>
            <md:ChannelMapping>stereo</md:ChannelMapping>
        </md:Encoding>
        <md:Channels>2</md:Channels>
        <md:TrackReference>3</md:TrackReference>
        <manifest:ContainerReference>
            <manifest:ContainerIdentifier>
                <md:Namespace>md</md:Namespace>
                <md:Identifier>md:apid:org:blueskyfilm.com:licks1:feature.audio20.en</md:Identifier>
                <md:Location>file://resources/Licks_FTR_1080_2398p_51en_20en.mov</md:Location>
            </manifest:ContainerIdentifier>
        </manifest:ContainerReference>
    </manifest:Audio>...
```

I have error on element md:encoding.

```
$ xmllint --schema ~/Documents/workspace/manifest-v1.5.xsd licks_manifest.xml > report.txt
licks_manifest.xml:20: element Encoding: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}Encoding': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}TrackIdentifier, {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}Private, {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.5/manifest}ContainerReference ).
licks_manifest.xml:37: element Encoding: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}Encoding': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}Channels, {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}TrackReference, {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}TrackIdentifier, {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/md/v2.4/md}Private, {http://www.movielabs.com/schema/manifest/v1.5/manifest}ContainerReference ).
licks_manifest.xml fails to validate*
```

schema and reference is on movielabs.com
(http://movielabs.com/md/manifest/)

I'm afraid I do not understand fully well trackidentificator specification. Movie Labs still does not respond to questions, so I try here. If someone has experience and could direct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself. Tag em:Encoding must follow tag md:Type. Thank to Crieg from movielabs.com.